# Time Complexity of 1-pass lookup given input size N**2

Tags: time-complexity

Given a list of lists, i.e.
**[[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]**:
What is the time complexity of using nested For loops to see if each numeral from 1-9 is used once and only once? Furthermore, what would be the time complexity if the input is now a singular combined list, i.e. **[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]**?

Comment: How does your question relate to the title? You don't mention "1-pass" or "N" in the question. As you have defined the problem, you don't even need a loop, but just `return true` since the input is a constant (or in other words, there is no input).

Answer (score 1):

What really matters is the size of the input, not the format. Either you have a list of 9 elements or 9 lists with 1 element, you still have 9 elements to be checked in the worst case.

The answer to the question, as stated, would be `O(1)`, because you have a *constant* size input.
If what you mean is something like *Given N elements what is the time complexity of checking if all number between 1 and N are present*, then it would take linear time, i.e., `O(N)`.

Indeed, an option is to use a hash table (e.g., a python set) and check if the element is already in the set, if not adding it. Note that in using this specific option you would get an *expected* (but not guaranteed, due to potential collisions) linear time complexity algorithm.